# Substract one Step for current parameter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following t-sql:

```
declare @startno int = 1, @finishno int = 365, @AfterO float = 97
declare @daysbet int = 80, @decVal float = 0.10 / 100;

;with ctetest as
(
select    @startno as oDay, 1 as oBet, @AfterO as Prod
    union all
    select     oDay +1, case when ((oBet + 1) = @daysbet) then 0 else (oBet + 1) end,
    case when (Prod = 0) then @AfterO else
         case when ((oBet + 1) = @daysbet) then 0 else (Prod - (@decVal * Prod)) end
    end
    from ctetest
    where oDay+1 <= @finishno
    )
    select * into #t1 
from ctetest option (maxrecursion 0)

Select @daysbet oVal, AVG(Prod) aProd, SUM(Prod) * 24 sProd FROM #t1
```

So the result should be:

```
---------------------------------
oVal      aProd        sProd
---------------------------------
80        92.484       810168.297
```

My question is, how can I substract some value from `oVal` on single execute? For instance, If the `oVal` value is `80` the the 2nd record is 79, 3rd record is 78 and the other columns will follow. Result should be:

```
---------------------------------
oVal      aProd        sProd
---------------------------------
80        92.484       810168.297
79        92.xxx       810444.069
78        92.xxx       810675.718
ff.---->
until oVal reach 1
```

So, the simple way is, if the `@daysbet` is 80, then the average of Prod is 92.484. If the `@daysbet` is 79, then the average of Prod is 92 poin something. and so on... In single execute.

Does anyone have an idea for this situation? Please advice.
Thank you.

Comment: get a tally table of numbers (up to, say, 365), select the numbers from it less than or equal to your @daysbet value, then cross apply for your avg/sum values

Comment: `@startno int = 1, @finishno int = 365` - you have 365 iterations. How can `80` reach `1` after 365 subtractions of `1`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, i put it into temp table then do some calc like AVG and SUM. :)

Comment: @ZLK, cross apply? I didn't get you.

Comment: @Haminteu so ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, 1st, it will create 365 rows. 2nd, I put it into temp table, 3rd, do some calc. On the 3rd step, it will create a table with one record. I want to create a multiple record base on daysbet. If daysbet is 80, then the next record should be 79, 78, 77, 76. And of course, with the calculation follow.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you are after. Do you want accumulated sum and avg values from all days before the current day?

Comment: Its a terrible if I need to add the value for daysbet parameter one by one (80 --> execute --> copy the result --> paste. then I change 80 to 79 --> execute --> copy the result --> paste. and so on..).

Comment: @Haminteu and how is that related to question about rownumber?..

Comment: @IvanStarostin, I didn't get you with ROW_NUMBER(). Is that the answer or what?

Comment: @Haminteu I don't know. Is it? p.s. plenty of time for typing, no time for googling?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, while googling , I am asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

```
declare @startno int = 1, @finishno int = 365, @AfterO float = 97
declare @daysbet int = 80, @decVal float = 0.10 / 100;

if object_id(N'tempdb..#t1', N'U') is not null drop table #t1;
;with ctetest as
(
    select a2.[n], a1.* 
    from (select [oDay] = @startno, [oBet] = 1, [prod] = @AfterO) as a1
    cross join 
    (
        select top(@daysbet) [n] = row_number() over(order by spt1.[number])
        from master..spt_values as spt1 
        cross join master..spt_values as spt2
    ) as a2
    union all
    select  [n]
            ,[oDay] + 1
            ,case when ((oBet + 1) = [n]) then 0 else (oBet + 1) end
            ,case when (Prod = 0) then @AfterO else case when ((oBet + 1) = [n]) then 0 else (Prod - (@decVal * Prod)) end
    end
    from ctetest
    where oDay + 1 <= @finishno
    )
select * into #t1 
from ctetest option (maxrecursion 0)

select  [oVal] = t1.[n]
        ,[aProd] = avg(t1.[prod]) 
        ,[sProd] = sum(t1.[prod]) * 24
from #t1 as t1
group by t1.[n]
order by t1.[n] desc
```